# Oracle SQLPlus can run select statement, but not Create Package

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to create deployment scripts.

I have a batch file called Deploy.bat

```
@Echo Off
sqlplus -s UID/pwd@Server @.\runall.sql >> OracleDeploy.log 2> error.log
```

then in runall.sql I have

```
@test1.sql
EXIT
```

If I put the below statement, my batch file runs fine.

```
Select * from User_table;
```

However, if I put in a create table statement, SQLPlus seems to wait for input and hangs till I press Control + c and terminate batch job.

```
create table t1
(c1 varchar2(10));
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Your subject line says you can't create a package. Here you're trying to create a table. Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to create a package, as your subject line indicates, I suspect you need a trailing "/" on the last line of your script:

```
create package p1 as 
...
end p1;
/
```

A create table statement should work as you have defined it.